# xcode ios How do i make a viewcontroller refresh?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made a reset highscore button, but the highscorelabel is still my previous highscore until I leave the viewcontroller?
How do I refresh it when I press the reset button?

now i have the code:

```
-(Action)ResetScore
{

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];

}
```

And then I want it to refresh the scorelabel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an UILabel, you will have to define it as IBOulet and has to linked on Storyboard. Then

```
NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
valLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
```